# JasperReport Pattern work differently on two Java Project

Tags: java, formatting, jasper-reports

I have two different Java projects who use the exact same Jasper file, the data send are exactly same, the Locale of the two differents projects are the same, the Pattern of the jasper file is the same but not the result :

The result of the first project (JDK 1.8) :

[image]

And the result of the second project (JDK 16.0.2) :

[image]

The Pattern on Jasper (#,##0.00):

[image]

On the second project, the formatting is not correct, the space is missing on the thousands, what can i do to fix that ?

Comment: Try running your JDK 16 project with -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,SPI

Comment: Thanks, it now works !